# How to resolve this error in react native? ERROR: http could not be found within the project or in these directories: node_modules

Tags: android, react-native, http, node-modules

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY5Rn.png)
 BUNDLE  ./index.js 

error: Error: Unable to resolve module http from /home/divum/Param/param-wallet-mobile/node_modules/https-browserify/index.js: http could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../../node_modules

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:
 1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
 2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
 3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
 4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
> 1 | var http = require('http')
    |                     ^
  2 | var url = require('url')
  3 |
  4 | var https = module.exports
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/home/divum/Param/param-wallet-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:129:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/home/divum/Param/param-wallet-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
    at Object.resolve (/home/divum/Param/param-wallet-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (/home/divum/Param/param-wallet-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at /home/divum/Param/param-wallet-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (/home/divum/Param/param-wallet-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (/home/divum/Param/param-wallet-mobile/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
```

I tried these steps :

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

I also tried cleaning my gradle ( ./gradlew clean) & cleared the cache and restarted again (npx react-native start --reset-cache , npx react-native run-android)

Please help me out , this error keeps on poping up to me. I can't even run my project because of this issue.